# Is it possible to make a git diff that results in no changes?

Tags: git, comments, documentation, code-documentation

So this is probably a silly idea, and there are probably workarounds/other solutions to this. I am curious about these, but also curious about the specific answer to the following question.

Is it possible to create a diff for a commit that simply removes and adds the same exact code thereby giving you an opportunity to create a commit that is really just metadata to specific lines of code, i.e. way to create a comment that is ephemerally attached to the lines of code until those lines are changed?

Reason:
My git reflexes make me want to ensure that every commit is fully working code, that way you don't have to guess how many commits you need to pop off if you need to roll something back. However this essentially gives you a single commit message to apply to all lines of code changed in that commit. (Maybe this is my fundamental problem?)

If there was a way to create a non-diff, that I could create a commit on, I could simply add a "comment" (commit message) to a few lines of code, embedded in which would be the author of the "comment", and a date-stamp of when the "comment" was made.

Then I could just get rid of all hard comments (i.e. lines starting with // or # or whatever) in my code, and look at a blame if I want to look for comments. And if I ever change something I either have to intentionally perpetuate the comment, write a new one, or just leave it up to whatever functional change I made.  In this way you would never have a TODO that doesn't need to be done, and you would never have a NOTE that doesn't apply anymore once you've changed the code.

Comment: "My git reflexes make me want to ensure that every commit is fully working code." I totally agree, that is a good habit and puts us in a comfortable position!

Comment: Note a related issue: `git format-patch` cannot produce an empty diff (or more precisely, it can try but nothing can *read* the result). This used to create a bunch of side problems where rebase would drop such commits; cherry-pick is able to copy an "empty diff" commit and you had to make sure to use that. Modern (2.27+ I think, but I didn't check) Git defaults to this better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a diff for a commit that simply removes and adds the same exact code thereby giving you an opportunity to create a commit that is really just metadata to specific lines of code, i.e. way to create a comment that is ephemerally attached to the lines of code until those lines are changed?

Simply, No. Your example of a comment would be a code change and thus it would show up in the diff.

Some potential options:

1. You could create an empty commit as described in [SebDieBln's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70702478/184546), which has no changes and only a commit message, in which you could say whatever you'd like.
2. You could create 2 commits, where the second one undoes the first. One way to accomplish this is to make some changes in 1 commit, and then revert that commit which will make a 2nd commit. In this case, the diff between the parent of the first commit and the second commit will have no changes, but the diff between the parent of the first commit and the first commit will have your changes you wish to capture and possibly do something with.

Comment: This is an interesting option, however looking at the history would be insane.

Comment: @JordanDavidson I always suggest, when reverting commits, to say why in the details of the commit message. In the repo I work in daily, reverts usually happen when a Pull Request is completed to a shared branch, and then someone regrets it afterwards. The history gets a little hairy when someone later decides they want it back, and they revert the revert. ;) That being said, I actually have seen some reverts that were done on purpose along with a commit, for example if someone wanted to show how to do something one way, but went with another way, yet wanted to capture the other for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create a diff for a commit that simply removes and adds the same exact code.

`git` does not save a *diff* for each commit but a *[complete tree of folders and files](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)* (although in a very clever and efficient way). The diff you see is calculated on the fly by comparing the two trees referenced by the commit in question and its parent.

You can create a commit that does not change the code at all (i.e. it references the exact same tree as its parent commit) using the [--allow-empty](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---allow-empty) option. But this will give you no reference to any files or lines of code.